# Set an enum property using an integer & validate the argument

Tags: c#

**EDIT: I have changed the title of the question to include the validation of the argument, to be clearer what I am asking.**

I am attempting to create a class in C# which has a property that is set with an int and returns an enum, this may be really basic but I am a C# noob.

The setting by use of an int argument is a particular limitation that I won't go into and is something that is getting set over COM in Vbscript.

I am looking to create these RSSCalendarDay objects so they can be put in a list and each have a unique RSSCalendarRuleDay from Sunday to Saturday (1 to 7).

Its for part of a really basic approach to using xCal with local data to make recurring events.

My code so far is below and you can see the get & set are incomplete, I am stuck on the validation of the argument (check its an int first, etc), thats what I was previously trying to use dayOrderValue for, and all I could find online in relation was the use of int.Parse and int.TryParse but they were for parsing a string, not for what I want to do.

```
public class RSSCalendarDay {

    private RSSCalendarRuleDay? _dayOrder;
    /// <summary>
    /// Passed an Integer from 1 to 7 to represent the particular day of the week as an enum
    /// </summary>
    public RSSCalendarRuleDay? DayOrder {
        get {
                       // TODO
        } 
        set {
            if (value != null) {
                int dayOrderValue;
                if () {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid day order specified");
                }
                if(dayOrderValue < 1 || dayOrderValue > 7) {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid day type specified (out of day range of 1 to 7)");
                }
                _dayOrder = (RSSCalendarRuleDay) dayOrderValue;
            }
            else {
                _dayOrder = null;
            }
        } 
    }
    public DateTime? TimeOpens { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeCloses { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// These are the relevant BYDAY abbreviations used in the xCal recurring rule specification
    /// to represent what days a recurring event is open in a comma separated list
    /// </summary>
    public enum RSSCalendarRuleDay {
        SU=1,MO=2,TU=3,WE=4,TH=5,FR=6,SA=7
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define a property that is “set with an int and returns an enum”. By design, the getter and the setter of a property be declared of the same type.

However, what you can do is define two properties which both access the same backing field, one as your enum, and the other cast to an int:

```
public class RSSCalendarDay
{
    private RSSCalendarRuleDay? dayOrder;

    public RSSCalendarRuleDay? DayOrder
    {
        get { return this.dayOrder; }
        set { this.dayOrder = value; }
    }

    public int DayOrderInt
    {
        get { return this.dayOrder.HasValue ? (int)this.dayOrder: 0; }
        set { this.dayOrder = value != 0 ? (RSSCalendarRuleDay?)value : null; }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I have simplified your logic to set the backing field to null if you specify an int value of 0 (and vice versa); this may not be what you want.

Consequently, the two following assignments will have identically the same effect:

```
RSSCalendarDay cd1 = new RSSCalendarDay();
cd1.DayOrder = RSSCalendarRuleDay.TH;

RSSCalendarDay cd2 = new RSSCalendarDay();
cd2.DayOrderInt = 5;
```

**Edit**: If you want to perform validation of the argument, you can use a similar approach:

```
public class RSSCalendarDay
{
    private RSSCalendarRuleDay dayOrder;

    public RSSCalendarRuleDay DayOrder
    {
        get { return this.dayOrder; }
        set { this.dayOrder = value; }
    }

    public int DayOrderInt
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (int)this.dayOrder;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(RSSCalendarRuleDay), value))
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid day value specified (out of day range of 1 to 7).");
            this.dayOrder = (RSSCalendarRuleDay)value; 
        }
    }
}
```

`Enum.IsDefined` checks whether the enumeration contains the specified value. In your case, the condition is equivalent to `value < 1 || value > 7`.

Note that in the above code, `DayOrder` is not nullable, and `0` is considered an invalid day value.

**Edit<sub>2</sub>**: Re the default value issue: My personal preference is to define the 0<sup>th</sup> member of the enumeration to be unknown; to continue with your two-letter convention, I’m naming it `NA` (for “not available”).

```
public enum RSSCalendarRuleDay {
    NA=0,SU=1,MO=2,TU=3,WE=4,TH=5,FR=6,SA=7
}
```

This is convenient because, when you initialize an `RSSCalendarDay` instance without explicitly setting its `dayOrder` field, it would automatically default to `RSSCalendarRuleDay.NA`. The second snippet I gave above would also work unchanged with this alteration, since `Enum.IsDefined` would now accept a range of 0–7 (rather than 1–7).

Comment: Nice answer :) and I felt this bit "value != 0" was also important  but subtle, I'm going to use your suggestion instead. Thanks

Comment: I now think the second snippet might be closer to what you need. The first snippet merely substitutes `null` for `0`.

Comment: Just realized Stefan had explained `Enum.IsDefined` before me… +1 to him for suggesting it first.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert an int to an Enum like so

```
RSSCalendarRuleDay foo = Enum.ToObject(typeof(RSSCalendarRuleDay) , intValue);
```

Or by simply casting it

```
RSSCalendarRuleDay foo = (RSSCalendarRuleDay) intValue;
```

Do note that since you're using a setter, the setter will expect an Enum value, not an integer, so you will need to cast it **before** using the setter.

Do note that ToObject will always succeed, even if the value is not defined for the Enum.  if you want to do a bounds check, you can use the Enum.IsDefined method

```
var exists = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(RSSCalendarRuleDay) , intValue);
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear with my question name, I'm casting the int to an enum already in the setter but first I wanted to validate that the arg is an int, from your answers I'm beginning to think I don't need to.. I should just attempt the above and throw the relevant exception? Out of interest how does Enum.ToObject react to an intValue that isn't in the range of enum values?

Comment: The conversion would still succeed.  If you want to explicitly check whether the int value is defined for the Enum, you can use the 'IsDefined' method.  I'll add this to my answer to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks for the info about "IsDefined". + 1 to your answer and +1 to your comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't over-complicate your code: enums are represented internally by numbers (`int` per default), so it is possible to cast from an `int` to an `enum` value (and vice-versa).

So here's how you could simply do:

```
public RSSCalendarRuleDay DayOrder { get; set; }

...

RSSCalendarDay xx = new RSSCalendarDay(...)
xx.DayOrder = (DayOrder)4;  // Will set WE for the DayOrder property

...

// If you need to get the value as an int
int dayOrderAsInt = (int)xx.DayOrder;

// Still possible to affect invalid values however
RSSCalendarRuleDay z = (RSSCalendarRuleDay)8;

// So if you want to check for int validity:
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(RSSCalendarRuleDay), dayOrderAsInt))
{
    // If we're here, the value is valid !
}
```

Also, make sure you really need `DayOrder` to be nullable (if it's not the case, remove the ?).

Comment: +1 good answer. To be honest, I am not sure if it needs to be nullable. I take it if I don't set it the default would be 0 ? yet my enum range is specifically 1 to 7? Also since they represent days of the week, i dont want to set a default day.. still unsure about that one.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can't receive anything different than an `Enum` in the setter for your property since you declared it as `Enum`. One alternative could be something like this:

```
private int? dayOrderInt;

public int? DayOrderInt
{
     get { return dayOrderInt; }
     set { if (value < 1 || value > 7) throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is an invalid day of the week", value)); dayOrderInt = value; }
}

public RSSCalendarRuleDay? DayOrder
{
    get { if (DayOrderInt.HasValue) return (RSSCalendarRuleDay)DayOrderInt; return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
RSSCalendarRuleDay Example = (RSSCalendarRuleDay)1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is achievable. You are setting your property type to RSSCalendarRuleDay? and when you want to pass az integer to it the compiler will throw an error. And by the way this approach is very confusing (like when you intended to return an IEnumerable but sometimes you do return null).

Comment: Did you mean enum when you said IEnumerable? I was setting the property to null if the argument was null, I also forgot to set _dayOrder to null when the class is instantiated. I didn't see a reason to set the property with an enum value when the argument was null though.